# Add new classname for element onclick()

Tags: javascript

This is my code in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qn7JG/1/

```
function go_to(lat,lon,hinttext,balloontext,event){

var domElement =$(event.target);
domElement.addClass('selected');
console.log(domElement);

return false;
}
```

I'm want to add new classname, when I click by link.
How I can do it?

Comment: No. I need exactly onclick handler with 'this' param.

Comment: Are you using jQuery (it looks like it)? Did you consider trying to perform *any* research at all? Because I'm pretty sure that a search for 'add class name with jQuery' would have led you straight to [`addClass()`](http://api.jQuery.com/addClass/).

Comment: Yes, it is. I know, how to add class if I have id or class, for example:

Comment: $('#123').on('click', function() {
   $(this).addClass('selected');
   return false;
  });
But I need exactly onclick handler with 'this' param

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED** 
I was in hurry on last post an I forget **the most important *addClass*** :)))  
I hope you get the clue with jquery data params.

After a lot of testing I find a solution for you 
html:

```
 <div id="res">
<a href="" class="ff" data-lat="123 " data-long="321 " data-hinttext="some hit text !" data-ballon="balloontext" >textr123</a>
</div>
```

js:

```
  $('.ff').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var lat = $('.ff').data('lat');
    var long = $('.ff').data('long');
    var hinttext = $('.ff').data('hinttext');
    var balloontext = $('.ff').data('ballon');
alert(lat + long + hinttext + balloontext);

$(this).addClass('selected');

return false;
```

});
});

[**and the DEMO IS HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qn7JG/53/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(element_id).addClassName(newClassName);
```

It will simply Add the class name.It won't remove the previous class name.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).click(function(event) {
    var text = $(event.target.nodeName).selector;
$(text).addClass("newclass");
});
</script>
<style>
.newclass{
color: #00ff00;
}

</style>
<p>hello</p>
<input type="text" id="amount"/>
```

Comment: I hav't id's of elements. I want to get element by click.

Comment: try this:$(document).click(function(event) {
    var text = $(event.target.nodeName).selector;
$(text).addClass("newclass");
});